# What does "I'll give you bum" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw this sentence in the movie 'The Flamingo Kid'.
I've tried to look up the meaning of it in the dictionary, but I couldn't find.
Please, help me.

This's one line of the dialogue between a father and his son.
They're working together on the drainpipe in the kitchen, while sharing jokes with one another.
The father is a plumber.

- Father: Who taught you how to do this?
- Son: Some bum.
- Father: I'll give you bum.

Comment: This is a question that lacks context. But I shall go out on a limb. If I say to you: You are so lazy, such a bum. You can answer sarcastically: "I'll give you a bum." And then **go on** to say a lot more sh***. That is a typical use of: I'll give you [some word used by the **other speaker**]. But, like I said, there is context lacking here.

Comment: Well, I did my best at editing in some context, but all I found was a subtitles site, which doesn't say who's talking. zephyr kim, can you check to see if it's right (and possibly tell us who said these lines and what was happening in the movie)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a pre-set snarky response to any statement, strictly used as slang and it always follows the syntax similar to the one below:

"You put on too much makeup, it looks like you have a black eye." 
"Pscht, I'll give you a black eye!"

Comment: Agreed. Another example: A: "I'm really angry with you for saying what you did when we were arguing.", B: "Huh, *you're* angry! I'll give you angry!"  In this case it means that B thinks that their anger is greater (and more justified) than A's anger.